# Expect Script Telnet email script

Tags: windows, tcl, telnet, expect

Trying to use Expect Script the Active TCL in Windows to send an email out every it is run. Below is the code I have but there is an error message displayed below and would appreciate any help on how to avoid the problem. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect

spawn plink -telnet IP PORT
send "ehlo *******.com\r";
send "AUTH LOGIN\r";
expect "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6" sleep .1;
send "*************\r";
sleep .1;
expect "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6\r"
send "********\r";
sleep .1;
expect "235 Authentication succeeded\r";
send "MAIL from:******@*******.com\r";
expect "250 OK\r"
send "RCPT to:********@*********.com\r";
expect "250 Accepted\r"
send "DATA\r";
send "!!!TEXT HERE!!!\r";
send ".\r";
send "QUIT\r";
exit
```

Getting a error:

```
Error in startup script

send: spawn id exp2 not open
           while executing
"send "MAIL from:*****@******.com\r""
   (file "***.tcl" line 16)
```

Any ideas on what is wrong here????

Comment: Apparently, mail server closes your connection. Do you see the output and doesn't it say why it drops a connection? (Also I'd recommend to wait for its `220...` banner, or at least sleep a bit, before you send anything).

Answer (score 5):

I think because the remote host closed the connection and plink exited.

Why don't you use the `smtp` package of tcllib?
It is much easier to use than talking raw smtp over plink with expect.

To summarize: you use plink for telnet, a thing that you can do with tcl `socket`s already.
You talk smtp, something where many libs exists that makes using it much easier.

Example of sending mail with pure tcl:

```
package require mime
package require smtp

set tok [::mime::initialize \
    -canonical text/plain \
    -header {From sender@address.example.com} \
    -string {Some Text Here}]
::smtp::sendmessage $tok \
    -servers IP \
    -ports PORT \
    -username ****** \
    -password ****** \
    -recipients recipient@address.example.com \
    -originator sender@address.example.com
::mime::finalize $tok
```

Comment: New to expect/TCL script.
How would I go about accomplishing what I am trying above using the smtp package?

Or is there a way to avoid it closing?

Comment: Install tcllib, start your script with `package require smtp`, then see examples at http://wiki.tcl.tk/1256.

Comment: To install tcllib, if you are on a *nix system, just use your packet manager to install tcllib. On windows, if you have ActiveState's Tcl distribution, you can do `teacup install smtp` and `teacup install mime` on the command line or you download it from [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcllib/) and just execute that (the default values are usually good).

Comment: What error is displayed? The first line is that matters. Edit: just tried the code, works for me.

Comment: I'm guessing he's not installed the required packages, configured the security or something like that…

Comment: I am using a windows machine. THE ERROR:
error in -originator: found phrase instead of mailbox(Computers name end-of-input) while executing "error"error in $who: $aprops(error)"" (Procedure"::smtp::sendmessage" line 161) invoked from within "::smtp::sendmessage $tok \
-servers ****** \
-ports *** \
-username ******* \
etc...

Comment: What machine/OS are you running?

Comment: Ok, try to specify the -originator. It works on my side, because my username is "Johannes", not "Johannes Kuhn". Edited Answer.

Comment: Okay did that but new error lol.

Handshake failed: resource temporarily unavailable while executing
"::tls::handshake $state(sd)"
 invoked from within
"::smtp::sendmessage $tok \
-servers ***** \
-ports ****
etc....

Comment: New error :(
key message-id not in header while executing "error" key $miced not in header"" (procedure"::mime::getheader" line 24) invoked from within "::mime::getheader $part ${message-idL}" invoked from within "::smtp::sendmessage $tok \ etc.....

Comment: Here is current code

`code
package require mime
package require smtp

set tok [::mime::initialize \
    -canonical text/plain \
    -header {From email@email.com} \
    -string {Some Text Here}]
::smtp::sendmessage $tok \
    -servers ip \
    -ports prt \
    -usetls false \
    -originator org \
    -username user \
    -password pass\
    -recipients email@email.com
::mime::finalize $tok
`