# write colored font in email using tcl

Tags: html, linux, fonts, tcl, mime

I automate a network switch using Tcl and expect scripts on my Fedora 12. The test logs and result with attachments are sent to an email inbox (office 365)-browser and outlook modes.

I would like to know if there is a way to make the color fonts appear in my email using TCL or shell script.

For example in the report sent to email, the text "Passed" should appear in  Green-bold and the font "failed" must appear in Red-bold. Will tput be useful?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any comments on how htmlgen, exmh or xmlgen might be useful? I'm Not using Tk though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is a simple script that I use to send mails (you might need to provide a username/password for `smtp::sendmessage`)

```
set textpart [::mime::initialize -canonical text/plain -string {Hello World}]
set htmlpart [::mime::initialize -canonical text/html -string  {<font color="green">Hello World</font>}]
set tok [::mime::initialize -canonical multipart/alternative -parts [list $textpart $htmlpart] -header {From test@example.com}]
::mime::setheader $tok Subject {Hello World}
::smtp::sendmessage $tok -servers smtp.example.com -recipients recipient@example.com -originator test@example.com
::mime::finalize $tok -subordinates all
```

Some notes:

- You can use different messages for html and plain text, but you should include all information in both. The client usually picks the better format that it can display.
- If you want to send attachments, you have to add an other `multipart/mixed`, (build it like the `multipart/alternative`), the first part of it should be the message (your `multipart/alternative`) the other parts are the attachments.
- Depending on some [more or less obscure circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695265/expect-script-telnet-email-script/14695385#14695385), the smtp and the mime package use some invalid system defaults (like your username with a space). If this happens, you have to provide extra information to one or more of this commands.

Comment: mime::initialize -canonical text/html multipart/mixed -encoding base64 -string $body] set body "<font size=12><font face=Arial><b><font color=green>Passed</b></font>"         works fine for attachment sending

Answer (score 3):

Just use html email (with `content-type: text/html` header) and inline css to colorize it.

`Passed` should be

```
<span style="color:green"><font color="green"></font></span>
```

Here `span` provides styling
`font` provides fallback if span does not work. Some email clients may strip those inline styles.

Comment: Note that sending html only mails is frowned upon. If you don't send the mail to yourself then send a multipart/alternative with both a text/html and a text/plain version. The [mime](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/mime.html) package of the Tcllib can help you with that.

Comment: @johannes Please tell me if this is correct.  <pre> <code>
set mime_msg [mime::initialize -canonical "text/html" "multipart/alternative eml" -encoding "US-ASCII" -string $body] 
<p><span style="color:green">Passed</span><span style="color:red">Failed</span></p>

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for two different things: color text in email and color text in the shell. The others already answer the email part, so I would like to address the shell part. For terminal output, I use the `term::ansi::send` package. Here is a sample:

```
package require cmdline
package require term::ansi::send

proc color_puts {args} {
    # Parse the command line args
    set options {
        {bg.arg default "The background color"}
        {fg.arg default "The foreground color"}
        {nonewline "" "no ending new line"}
        {channel.arg stdout "Which channel to write to"}
    }
    array set opt [cmdline::getoptions args $options]

    # Set the foreground/background colors
    ::term::ansi::send::sda_fg$opt(fg)
    ::term::ansi::send::sda_bg$opt(bg)

    # puts
    if {$opt(nonewline)} {
        puts -nonewline $opt(channel) [lindex $args end]
    } else {
        puts $opt(channel) [lindex $args end]
    }

    # Reset the foreground/background colors to default
    ::term::ansi::send::sda_fgdefault
    ::term::ansi::send::sda_bgdefault
}

#
# Test
#

puts "\n"
color_puts -nonewline -fg magenta "TEST"
color_puts -nonewline -fg blue    " RESULTS"
puts "\n"

color_puts -fg green "test_001 Up/down direction movements passed"
color_puts -fg red "test_002 Left/right direction movements failed"
```

#### Discussion

- The applicable flags to `color_puts` are `-bg` for background color, `-fg` for foreground color, `-nonewline` for suppressing the new line character output, and `-channel` to direct the output to the file.
- The available colors are black, blue, red, green, yellow, magenta, cyan, white, and default. For more information, look up the `term::ansi::send` package.

Comment: I was checking if there is a way with shell coding, I'm sorry if the sentence was misguiding. Thank you.